# Javascript crop function without displaying image

Tags: javascript

First of all, I'm very new to javascript. I'm trying to develop a javascript function which takes an image and returns a cropped version of that image. By looking around on google I've found that I probably need to use a canvas in some way to accomplish this task. But does that mean I have to display the image on my page?

I've also looked at different javascript image processing libraries for a similar function, for example Pixastic's Crop, but I have no idea how to use it to solve my particular problem. So now I'm turning to you guys for help. Please guide me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pixastic's Crop solution seems easy to implement and uses the canvas. It would do the job as long as you don't need to support Internet Explorer 7 or 8.

Otherwise, you can simply use CSS `overflow:hidden;`  to do a client side cropping.

Pixastic Solution: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/crop/, check out the Example Code tab.

Here is a working example for Pixastic and the CSS solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/EB6P7/1/

I used the jQuery plugin for Pixastic.

--

If you don't need to save the image on the server side I recommand using the CSS solution as it doesn't rely on Javascript and achieve the same result as Pixastic.

If there's anything you don't understand, ask me as I don't know your level in HTML/CSS.

Comment: As written in the question, I have no idea how to use Pixastic's crop to accomplish the task. If you could show me an example of how it could be done I would be very grateful!

Comment: I'm starting to understand a bit now, but what if I want to use variables? I don't know the exact syntax for javascript, but like var croppedImage = crop(originalImage, x, y, width, height);?

Comment: Here is an example with a JavaScript function: http://jsfiddle.net/EB6P7/6/. Do you know jQuery? I could do a plain JavaScript example if you prefer.

Comment: All I know is that it's a javascript library. I would like to have a javascript function without HTML code if possible. A function which takes an image, some coordinates, "physically" crops it and returns the cropped image. Not even sure it's possible.. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Pixastic works with the DOM. As far as I know, the image need to be put in the HTML before using Pixastic. So, it would be impossible to do a crop without using HTML. But there is a function that can convert a canvas into an image (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) So, after Pixastic, you could target the canvas and convert it to an image, but you have to use HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your problem is only cropping and not saving the cropped image, the simplest solution I would say is to position the image using CSS inside a div and show only the cropped area.

If you want to save then I wish you need to use some library on the server side to crop and save

Comment: Well I may not want to save the cropped image right away, but I want to return it from the crop function. So that's not he solution I'm looking for, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the CSS Clipping feature is a solution for you?

```
#someImage
{
 clip:rect(50px 100px 130px auto);
}
```

Comment: Clip, as I've understood it, only displays a part or the image, and does not "physically" crop the image, but thanks!